# Adding all the instances in a package to a List with Spring

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I have a class "Box" with add method accepting all the fruits:

```
  public class Box {
        List <IFruit> fruits;

        public void add (IFruit fruit) {
             fruits.add(fruit);
        }
  }
```

I would like to define with Spring's applicationContext.xml a singleton instance of this class, which would have all the IFruits implementations added (those appear in a package x.y.fruits, for inst. x.y.fruits.Apple).

The first part is easy:

```
  <bean id="box" class="x.y.Box"/>
```

But how to wire all the IFruit instances?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this question and answer what are you looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9144271/280244

Comment: By instances you mean declared beans or you want to collect single instances of all implementing classes without actually declaring them as beans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `@Autowire` the field, you do not need to define anything, Spring will find all instances of the `IFruit` interface in the application context and load them in.

```
public class Box {
    @Autowired
    List <IFruit> fruits; //This should contain all IFruit's in the ApplicationContext

    public void add (IFruit fruit) {
         fruits.add(fruit);
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to add the element `<context:annotation-config/>` to your xml configuration for `@Autowired` to work...

Answer (score 2):

If you create a setter for the list, say `setFruits`, you can wire it like this:

```
<bean id="box" class="x.y.Box">
  <property name="fruits">
    <list>
      <ref bean="fruit1" />
      <ref bean="fruit2" />
      ...
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fruit1" class="x.y.fruits.Apple" />
...
```

You can also do this similarly using constructor injection.

Comment: That's nice! But do I have to list all the classes? I would really like to use all the classes in a given package.

Comment: @Vojtěch: You will have to list the classes in one place or the other. There is no way to automatically find all classes in a given package.